# Floating Button with Numeric Count Value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: er]

Unable to add the numeric part to the Floating Button

Comment: What do you mean by "Unable to add the numeric part to the Floating Button". What have you tried. Your input could be useful

Comment: i meant... for the bell i am simply adding an image to a button.... but the numeric value is suppose to come from the webservice... which might change

Comment: OK by my understanding. All you need is a simple overlap of view with a TapGesture. I'll try to add an Answer for it. Is this what you are looking for? Or [SfBadgeView](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/badge-view/getting-started) can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea of layouting frame inside RealtiveLayout, do change as per your need.

```cs
<RelativeLayout
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    Margin="0,30,0,0"
    HeightRequest="75"
    WidthRequest="75"
    IsClippedToBounds="False">
    <RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </RelativeLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Frame
        x:Name="floatMainButton"
        Padding="0"
        HeightRequest="75"
        CornerRadius="38"
        WidthRequest="75"/>
    <Frame
        BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
        HeightRequest="25"
        WidthRequest="25"
        Padding="0"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=floatMainButton, Factor=0.75, Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=floatMainButton, Factor=-0.10, Property=Height}"
        CornerRadius="13">
        <Label
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            TextColor="White"
            Text="{Binding Count}"/>
    </Frame>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: UI result]

Is this what you are looking for

Comment for any query...